# Type error in a min-and-max function

Tags: haskell, types, io, typeerror

I am working on a haskell project and have a minmax function that gets the minimum and maximum of a list and returns them in a tuple pair like so:

```
λ> minmax [1,2,3]
(1,3)
λ> minmax [4,2,5,9]
(2,9)
```

Now I am implementing a user input list that recursively loops until a cancel input is put in then the list completes which then needs to utilize my minmax function, the problem i'm having is that it's not obviously the same type as a simple list when done because it's throwing me type errors.

```
minmax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> (a,a)
minmax [] = error "Null"
minmax (x:xs) = (minimum (x:xs), maximum (x:xs))

convertIO :: IO Int
convertIO = do
    line <- getLine
    return (read line :: Int)

minmaxlist :: IO [Int]
minmaxlist = do
    number <- convertIO
    if(number /= 0)
        then (do 
            int_list <- minmaxlist
            return (minmax (number:int_list)))
    else return []
```

Is throwing me this specific error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `(Int, Int)'
```

Though a list of integers is exactly what i'm passing through via (number:int_list) and if I do pass it a list of integers it returns the tuple fine. Why is it throwing me errors here? Does it have to do with it being from type IO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is a good one - both `minmax` and the way you are producing your `IO [Int]` seems resonable - I just would push the application of `minmax` out of the list-generation all togehter:

```
module Main where

minmax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> (a,a)
minmax [] = error "Null"
minmax (x:xs) = (minimum (x:xs), maximum (x:xs))

convertIO :: IO Int
convertIO = do
    line <- getLine
    return (read line :: Int)

ioInts :: IO [Int]
ioInts = do
    number <-convertIO
    if number /= 0
      then do 
        int_list <- ioInts
        return (number:int_list)
      else return []

minmaxIO :: IO (Int,Int)
minmaxIO = do
  list <- ioInts
  return $ minmax list

main :: IO ()
main = do
  val <- minmaxIO
  print val
```

you can make this all a bit shorter with operators like `(<$>)` but I think you are more comfortable with the `do` notation

As you can see I just added another `IO` computation `minmaxIO` that applies `minmax` to the list produced by `ioInts` (which I renamed from your `minmaxlist`) - the other stuff if basically still yours

Comment: So in this instance you're casting the returned list of type IO [Int] into a list? Could you go into more detail on what you did casting wise for minmaxIO?

Comment: Specifically is the list you set of type IO Int? or is it Int?

Comment: there is no actual casting - your function `convertIO` is of type `IO Int`, so `number <- convertIO` pulls out an `Int` - that fixes all the types here (of course `Int` is an instance of `Ord`) - the value `list` I pull out with `list <- ioInts` will have type `[Int]` (if you do `x <- y` and `y :: IO a` then `y` must be `x :: a`)

Comment: So the way I understand, what I was trying to is impossible because everytime the function ioInts gets called and set int_list it would need to be getting it from a list of Int, and not of (Int, Int) which is what it was returning.

Comment: yes exactly - the types on the both branches of your `if` would not have matched either - you could use the *hack*/trick @SimonH proposed but IMO it's much clearer this way

Answer (score 2):

`minmaxlist :: IO [Int]` states that `minmaxlist` is an `IO` action that returns a list of `Int`. However, it tries to return the result of `minmax` (in `return (minmax (number:int_list)))`), which is of type `(Int, Int)`.

So, what do you want `minmaxlist` to return?

Comment: The result of minmax when call, so akin to type of minmax, i've tried casting it, but it always throws me an error that it "expects a contraint but IO [Int] has kind '*' "

Answer (score 0):

You were very close - don't use a tuple, but return a list instead

```
minmax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
minmax [] = error "Null"
minmax xs = [minimum xs, maximum xs]
```

Comment: I have to declare it of [Int] because that's the only way my list will accumulate, so i'm approaching this wrong then?

Comment: Having the same issue with the type [Int] trying to be the return but asking for ([Int], [Int])